# Cannot access website with urllib

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I want to access a specific website but it is somehow blocked because it works just fine with other websites.
Here is my current code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

my_url = "https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics"
req = Request(my_url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
page = urlopen(req).read()
```

and this is my error I get:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in 
http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

As you see I am using a header. Is there an other method I could use to bypass the blocking?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to fake the `user-agent`

Comment: I got the solution, it includes cookies. I'll write an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already realized, you'll need to add enough headers to make it look like you are an ordinary browser.

First of all, let me remark that the page also 403s on me if I visit it without having any cookies from the site. Not particularly nice design, but so be it.

Now, let's assume that you actually manage to get through in your ordinary browser. Then, note that browsers such as Firefox and Chrome allow you to turn their requests into curl equivalents, which allows you to readily experiment:

```
$ curl -I "https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --compressed -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cookie: visid_incap_...; incap_ses_453_..." -H "DNT: 1" -H "Host: www.whoscored.com" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

With this, the problem turns into one of removing headers until the server no longer accepts requests.

Indeed, in your particular case, you'll find that you can remove anything but

```
-H "Cookie: visid_incap_...; incap_ses_..."
```

so you need to set up at least one prior request to get those cookies. Now, the relevant cookies are actually set on the 403ing response, so you can simply take them from there:

```
$ curl -I "https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics"
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
....
Set-Cookie: visid_incap_...; expires=Mon, 01 Apr 2019 09:22:14 GMT; path=/; Domain=.whoscored.com
Set-Cookie: incap_ses_...; path=/; Domain=.whoscored.com
```

That is, you'll want to first visit the page, knowing that you'll get a 403, take note of the cookies provided to you, and re-request the same page but with the cookies added.

Comment: 13 seconds later ;)

Comment: @linusg: I'll have to skip proofreading next time ... At least we're wonderfully well-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

So, what I've tried is visiting the page with Firefox, copying the `curl` command for `https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics` and removing one header each time I run it in the terminal, except for the user agent. It stopped working when I removed the `Cookie`-header:

```
<html style="height:100%">
   <head>
      <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   </head>
   <body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe src="/_Incapsula_Resource?CWUDNSAI=18&xinfo=9-102892494-0%200NNN%20RT%281522595804827%20135%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B15%284%2c200%2c0%29%20U2&incident_id=534000500096779297-388792508527018793&edet=15&cinfo=04000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 534000500096779297-388792508527018793</iframe></body>
</html>
```

For some strange reason the same happens in the browser when you delete the cookie they gave you. It gives an 403.

Anyways, you may use my or your cookie and it works:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

my_url = "https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics"
req = Request(my_url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'Cookie': 'visid_incap_774904=W2dv4v7LQ9O+mAgXMTXNEkf0wFoAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAAa0bYG0xZT8EYzEjek6QAz; incap_ses_534_774904=hy1MMZjKpnSDJyYmoCZpB0f0wFoAAAAAZA+Th6cYjAoseY9Kq7vrFA=='
})
page = urlopen(req).read()
```